# Hashmap <String, Object>: iterate and get values in each key

Tags: java, hashmap

I have users as my hashmap . How would I be able to display each value String from my hashmap using its key? Sample key: "1", Sample value: "name: flower" "age: 6". Is there simpler way for to display flower and 6?

```
     Iterator it = users.entrySet().iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
                Log.e(pair.getKey().toString(), " = " + pair.getValue());
                it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
            }
```

Comment: Start by learning about generics. They exist since Java 5. We're at Java 9.

Answer (score 1):

As with most things, there are many ways this can be achieved. The simplest way I find that can iterate over the key/value pairs is as follows:

```
for (String key : map.keySet()) {
   System.out.println(key + " : " + map.get(key).toString());
}
```

Another similarly simplistic solution would be:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, User> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " : " + entry.getValue().toString());
}
```

Just replace String with whatever the Class you have designated as the key.

**Edit:** If you are wanting to remove during the iteration, this solution would be inappropriate.

Comment: what i get when I use this is somewhat like "User@4ffc4c8"

Comment: I think he wants to remove every entry after looping. This is not possible with your current implementation since this will yield a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Comment: @AndI What is the signature of your HashMap? Is it `Map<String, User>` or `Map<String, Object>`?

Comment: it's HashMap<String, User>

Comment: The simplest way would be to iterate over the `entrySet` directly.

Comment: The reason you would get something like "User@4ffc4c8" would be because you have not over-ridden the public String toString() method. Note map.get(key) returns an object reference associated to the key, so you can deal with the object as you wish.

Comment: Thanks all. It went well when i iterated through the entry set value (which is an object in my hashmap). Something like this: users.get(key).getFullname().toString(). I forgot to went inside the object. Thanks All!

Comment: Not a problem. As @Martijn has noted, if you are wanting to remove during iteration this will throw a ConcurrentModificationException. Though if you are not wanting to remove, this is probably the most elegant solution.